# Use jQuery Tabs within each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script so that I can make tabs very easy. But I can't have two, three, four and so on - tab function on the same page. I've tried to wrap into an each.function, but I just don't work for me. The tab changes on both rows at the same time :/

I use WordPress so the HTML markup is a little long so I've created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Cadima-io/pen/jKPRzE).

I also want this: if you click on the selected tab, I want it to be not active, like an accordion.

Markup here:

```js
(function($) {
 $('.section .row').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.nav_wrap .tab').on('click', function() { 
   show_content($(this).index());
  });
 });

 
 show_content(99);  // choose 0 to start with first tab
 
 function show_content(index) {
  $('.row').each(function() {
   // Make the content visible
   $(this).find('.content_wrap .content.visible').removeClass('visible');
   $(this).find('.content_wrap .content:nth-of-type(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('visible');
  
   // Set the tab to selected
   $(this).find('.nav_wrap .tab.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).find('.nav_wrap .tab:nth-of-type(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('selected');
  });
 }
 
 
  })(jQuery);
```

```css
.row {
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.nav_wrap, .content_wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.tab, .content {
  padding: 20px;
}
.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab:hover,
.tab.selected {
  background:pink;
}
.content_wrap .content {
    display: none;
}
.content_wrap .content.visible {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="nav_wrap">
            <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
            <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
            <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_wrap">
            <div class="content">Tab 1 content goes here</div>
            <div class="content">Tab 2 content goes here</div>
            <div class="content">Tab 3 content goes here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="nav_wrap">
            <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
            <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
            <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_wrap">
            <div class="content">Tab 1 content goes here</div>
            <div class="content">Tab 2 content goes here</div>
            <div class="content">Tab 3 content goes here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I cannot understand your question. Can you explain where you got problem?

Comment: Hi :) Have you tried the demo?... When you click the tabs it changes in both rows at the same time

Comment: Yes, It changes. So you want to be changed of clicked one only?

Comment: Yes.. If i click on track 1 only content of track one should be shown..

Comment: ok, I have added my answer hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of clicked element and add class to next `content` of clicked element based on clicked element index. Here I have updated your above code into one function. And I have checked if the clicked has `selected` class or not with `hasClass()` method. I guess this is what you are looking for.

```js
(function($) {
  $('.nav_wrap .tab').on('click', function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if(!$(this).parent().next().find('.content').eq($(this).index()).hasClass('visible')) {
      $(this).parent().next().find('.visible').removeClass('visible');
    }  $(this).parent().next().find('.content').eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('visible');
 }); 
  })(jQuery);
```

```css
.row {
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.nav_wrap, .content_wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.tab, .content {
  padding: 20px;
}
.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab:hover,
.tab.selected {
  background:pink;
}
.content_wrap .content {
    display: none;
}
.content_wrap .content.visible {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="nav_wrap">
            <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
            <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
            <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_wrap">
            <div class="content">Tab 1 content goes here</div>
            <div class="content">Tab 2 content goes here</div>
            <div class="content">Tab 3 content goes here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="nav_wrap">
            <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
            <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
            <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_wrap">
            <div class="content">Tab 1 content goes here</div>
            <div class="content">Tab 2 content goes here</div>
            <div class="content">Tab 3 content goes here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AWESOME!! Thanks :) - will you please +1 my question?

Comment: THANKS! Can you add this: When clicked on active tab it goes back to hide all tabs content?

Comment: It Works perfectly! Thank you again :)